# PowerShell script to download SharePoint attachments (Excel) with certain worksheet name

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that will scan a SharePoint list and download an excel spreadsheet if it has a certain worksheet name.

I'm not sure of where to start as far as syntax goes... Has anyone provided a solution like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will have to download all the attachments until you find the one you need. Then return it as a result.
Once you have downloaded the attachment, you can use the excel COM API to open it and look for a particular worksheet. Examples can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx